# Kendo UI Angular 2 is Free?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I will build a new application by angular 2 and i want to use **Kendo ui Angular 2**,
 so i want to know :

1. Kendo ui Angular 2 is **free** or licensed ?

Answer (score 4):

Kendo UI Core is the only Kendo framework open-source.

- [Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/license-agreement/kendo-ui-core)

Any other Kendo suite is released within commercial license:

- [Kendo UI Complete](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/license-agreement/kendo-ui-complete)
- [Kendo UI Professional](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/license-agreement/kendo-ui-professional)

On top of the .js files you might find this section:

> Kendo UI v2016.1.412 (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui)
> Copyright 2016 Telerik AD. All rights reserved.
>
> Kendo UI commercial licenses may be obtained at
> http://www.telerik.com/purchase/license-agreement/kendo-ui-complete
> If you do not own a commercial license, this file shall be governed by
> the trial license terms.

Comment: i have been used kendo ui professional trial version for jquery(grid , charts) on old project and this project already published online since one year and still working !! what does it mean ?
@Giovanni

Comment: Sure it works but as licence states you are not allowed to use that product in public server or for commercial porpouses. I definitely suggest you to evaluate the license as soon as possible.